# How to access iterator object of a given type

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a client in Hyperledger Fabric application. There, for one query, I am getting an object which I don't know how to access. When I printed the object into the console

```
 console.log(result);
```

it gives me the following value.

```
[object Object]
```

According to [documentation](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getHistoryForKey__anchor), I am getting `HistoryQueryIterator object`

How can I access, iterate this object in my nodejs application?

In the debig mode, I can it is a buffer of ints.

Comment: Using that notation specifically, you are implicitly calling `result.toString()`. If you want to have a cleaner read of what `result` is, just `console.log(result);` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use util.inspect():

```
const util = require('util')

console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))

// alternative shortcut
console.log(util.inspect(myObject, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
```

Outputs

```
{ a: 'a',  b: { c: 'c', d: { e: 'e', f: { g: 'g', h: { i: 'i' } } } }
```

See https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options